# show table results as it's loading done and get data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have one main DIV inside that div I have 6 different table which shows the responses of API I'm calling APIs from ajax

the thing is not every API gives results all the time so I need to display accordingly

right now I'm using `.hide` and `.show` in order to get specific result table.

the problem is if I get the data from 2nd API it will show the table at 2nd position and after that, if 5,6 gets responses they show-up now what is happening is if I get 3,4 APIs response they'll get space in between I want 3,4 result to be appended to the list.

so for user(front-end) they show like all apis are responding one-by-one and display data one-by-one.

```
<div class="insight text-center">   
<table id="ssl_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
<table id="links_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
<table id="tag_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
<table id="drupal_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
<table id="wp_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
<table id="zx_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
<table id="ada_table" class="table table-hover" style="color: black; position: relative; z-index: 1000; background: white;">
</table>
</div>
```

***i have 6 ajax like this***

```
$.ajax({
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "api_url",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "website_url
  }
}
).done(function (response) {
if (response.current) {
    $('#wp_table').show();
} else { 
    $('#wp_table').hide();
    console.log('Error :',response)
    }  
}).fail(function (jqXHR, response) {
    $('#wp_table').hide();
    console.log('Failed',response);

});
}
```

Comment: show us your script part where you are showing/hiding the tables

Comment: added the ajax in which im showing the table @SanchitPatiyal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I understand is, you make 6 `AJAX` calls and you don't know which one comes first and which one comes last, is that true?

OK, you don't need all that tables, just append the data to the `DIV` as soon as it comes:

jQuery:

```
$("#insight-text-center").append(YOUR DATA);
```

**Note**: you better append to an `ID` instead of a `class`.